# Where is the web server root directory in WAMP?

Tags: server, wamp, document-root

Also is the web server root directory the place where you put your site files and later acces them with localhost/file_name in the browser?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you installed WAMP to `c:\wamp` then I believe your webserver root directory would be `c:\wamp\www`, however this might vary depending on version.

Yes, this is where you would put your site files to access them through a browser.

Answer (score 23):

In WAMP the files are served by the Apache component (the A in WAMP).

In Apache, by default the files served are located in the subdirectory `htdocs` of the installation directory. But this can be changed, and is actually changed when WAMP installs Apache.

The location from where the files are served is named the `DocumentRoot`, and is defined using a variable in Apache configuration file. The default value is the subdirectory `htdocs` relative to what is named the `ServerRoot` directory.

By default the `ServerRoot` is the installation directory of Apache. However this can also be redefined into the configuration file, or using the `-d` option of the command `httpd` which is used to launch Apache. The value in the configuration file overrides the `-d` option.

The configuration file is by default `conf/httpd.conf` relative to `ServerRoot`. But this can be changed using the `-f` option of command httpd.

When WAMP installs itself, it modify the default configuration file with `DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/`. **The files to be served need to be located here** and not in the `htdocs` default directory.

You may change this location set by WAMP, either by modifying `DocumentRoot` in the default configuration file, or by using one of the two command line options `-f` or `-d` which point explicitly or implicity to a new configuration file which may hold a different value for `DocumentRoot` (in that case the new file needs to contain this definition, but also the rest of the configuration found in the default configuration file).

Answer (score 4):

Everything suggested by user "mins" is correct, and excellent information.

WAMP 2.5 provides a default Server Configuration display when you enter localhost into your browser.  This maps to c:\wamp\www, as described in previous posts.  Creating subdirectories under www will cause Projects to appear on this display.  A click and you're in your project.

I have various projects under different directory structures, sometimes on shared drives which makes this centralized location of files inconvenient.  Luckily, there is a second feature of WAMP 2.5, an Alias, which makes specifying the location of one (or more) disparate web directories quite easy.  No editing of configuration files.  Using the WAMP menu, choose Apache > Alias directories > Add an Alias.

WAMP has evolved nicely to provide support for a variety of developer preferences.

Comment: Adding an alias worked for me! Now I can enter the url without having to enter /public directory! Cheerio!

Answer (score 3):

If you use Bitnami installer for wampstack, go to:

c:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.6.24-0/apache/conf  (of course your version number may be different)

Open the file:
httpd.conf in a text editor like Visual Studio code or Notepad ++

Do a search for "DocumentRoot". See image.

[image: Screenshot]

You will be able to change the directory in this file.

Answer (score 2):

To check what is your root directory go to httpd.conf file of apache and search for "DocumentRoot".The location following it is your root directory

Comment: Most of the answers presume that user installed wampserver in wamp folder. This answer is handy! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this is the path to the web root directory c:\wamp\www

you can create different projects by adding different folders to this directory and call them like:

localhost/project1  from browser

this will run the index.html or index.php, lying inside project1

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here's how I get there using Version 3.0.6 on Windows