# How to resolve linux folder name vs Win7 localhost folder name

Tags: php, localhost, fopen

I have a text file on my Linux website and I'm trying to run my website php code on my Win7 localhost machine.

The text file on the server is located at:
/home/vault/public_html/ssfiles/mysql.txt

On my local machine I'm running Apache/PHP/MySQL and my php files are located in:
C:\wamp\www\

How do I get my php script to open the file with the first folder string and to also work locally with the second folder string?

I'm new to running php on my local machine and have always run my php scripts directly on the Linux server...so I'm not sure how to resolve this?

Is there a php.ini setting that handles this? based on what machine the script is executing on?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If you place the files in htdocs folder in c:\wampp\   you can directly access the file with localhost/folder_name/file_name.php   from broswer

Comment: My htdocs folder is buried in C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\htdocs. Inside that folder is one file: index.html which displays It Works!. However I can't seem to get that file to actually display in my browser using: http://localhost/index.html ???

Comment: See this link it my help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233572/where-is-the-web-server-root-directory-in-wamp