# PHP code doesn't show while using Dreamweaver

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I create a new HTML file for my project using Dreamweaver and i added a simple php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

so far nothing is appearing while i open the file with google chrome and IE, any thoughts?

Comment: How are you opening the file in Chrome or IE?

Comment: you need to be running a websever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP requires a webserver and an interpreter. Browsers cannot handle PHP on its own.

Look at [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

Answer (score 4):

PHP has to be executed on the server. Upload it to a web server that supports PHP, or install your own web server locally such as WAMP. You then need to access the file with a URL rather than just opening it. A local URL will look like `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1/`.

Your file also needs to have the extension `.php` if it contains PHP code. If you really want to use PHP inside a `.html` file, your web server will need to be set up specially to handle this.

Comment: i am using WAMP, do u suggest that i need to open the php file with it ?

Comment: Your PHP file needs to be in WAMP's web root folder, then you can view the page using your web browser by accessing the appropriate URL. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233572/where-is-the-web-server-root-directory-in-wamp

Comment: ahh ok ok , it worked now, i had to change the extension of my file to .php , .html didn't work at all @nullability

Answer (score 0):

A good idea to check if your php file is working properly is to load phpinfo function. 
This function will show details about your PHP installation:

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

If what you see on the screen is this php code with the entire opening and closing tags (), then you are not running the page with PHP.