# Does my script need anything else to have the PHP script run when I open the browser?

Tags: php, html

I'm learning web development and embedding PHP into the website. In running a basic HTML script like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    echo "Hello World";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

the Hello World, does not show in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the browser, view the page source.  What do you see?  Specifically, do you see the PHP code itself?

Comment: I'm guessing you named the 'basic html script' as something with `.html` on the end... ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, still no luck

Comment: You need to upload it into your PHP server. Please take a look at question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233572/where-is-the-web-server-root-directory-in-wamp

Comment: I see, so PHP isn't visible in the browse like HTML then?

Answer (score 0):

Save as a .php file ext name. If that doesn't work let me know. Thanks

Comment: I tried that, but it hasn't worked. I'm using visual studio community if thats of use?

Comment: Hi sorry for delayed response, set up a XAMP or WAMP environment and run a local server. This is due to PHP being a server-side language.