# php my admin to link my sql database localhost directory doesn't exist

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp, servermanager

This is what I get when trying to log into phpmyadmin through wamp server:

[image]

I have tried all of the solutions that could be found on the internet excluding the one using server manager because i don't have it and couldn't download it even using cmd or powershell.
can anybody help me?

Comment: Does the directory (given under `Physical Path` in the image) exist on your computer? and what are the contents of it ?

Comment: C:\inetpub\wwwroot   its does exist it contains three files (webconfig) (aspnet_client) and a test file i created

Comment: `\inetpub\wwwroot` is (default) for [Internet Information Service](https://www.iis.net/). The `A` in **WAMP** is from Apache,  I do not know the current default, but it used to be: [c:\wamp\www](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6233597/724039)